# How to import, export, and merge several GraphQL type definition in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

The file structure is like this:

```
.
├── typeDefs.js
├── server.js
└── types
     ├── types_index.js
     └── addressResolver
          ├── addressResolver_index.js
          ├── address.js
          ├── Mutation.js 
          └── Query.js
```

in `./types/addressResolver`, I saved GraphQL type definition files as the following:

- In `./types/addressResolver/address.js`

  ```
    export const Address = gql`
    type Address {
        id: ID!,
        customer_id: ID!,
        address_type: String!,
        address: String!
    }
  ```

  `
- In `./types/addressResolver/Mutation.js`

  ```
    export const addressMutation = gql`
    type Mutation {
        "Add a new address."
        addAddress(userId: String!, addressType: String!, address: String!): Boolean!
        "Delete an address."
        deleteAddress(userId: String!, addressType: String!, address: String!): Boolean!
    }
  ```

  `
- In `./types/addressResolver/Query.js`

  ```
    export const addressQuery = gql`
    type Query {
        resolveAddress(userId: String!, addressType: String!): Address!
    }
  ```

  `

I would like to pass these three gql from `./types/addressResolver/addressResolver_index.js` >> `./types/types_index.js` >> `./typeDefs.js`

So eventually, I would like to have something like the following in `./typeDefs.js`:

```
export const typeDefs = gql`
type Query{
    hello: String!
    cats:[Cat!]!
    resolveAddress(userId: String!, addressType: String!): Address!
    address:[Address!]!
}

type Address {
    id: ID!,
    customer_id: String!,
    address_type: String!,
    address: String!
}

type Cat{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}

type Mutation{
    createCat(name: String!): Cat!

    "Add a new address."
    addAddress(userId: String!, addressType: String!, address: String!): Boolean!

    "Delete an address."
    deleteAddress(userId: String!, addressType: String!, address: String!): Boolean!
}
`
```

What I'm doing right now is :

- In `./types/addressResolver/addressResolver_index.js`:

  ```
  export {Address} from './address.js';
  export {addressMutation} from './Mutation.js';
  export {addressQuery} from './Query.js';
  ```
- In `./types/types_index.js`:

  ```
  export {Address, addressMutation, addressQuery} from './addressResolver/index.js';
  ```
- In `./typeDefs.js`:

  ```
  import {Address, addressMutation, addressQuery} from './types/index.js';
  export const typeDefs = [Address, addressMutation, addressQuery]
  ```

But it does not work.

P.S. I'm using ES6, so I have to stick to `export` instead of `module.exports =`, and `import` instead of `require`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using the following code in the `./types/addressResolver/addressResolver_index.js`

```
import { mergeTypeDefs} from '@graphql-tools/merge';
import {Address} from './address.js';
import {addressMutation} from './Mutation.js';
import {addressQuery} from './Query.js';

const toMergeTypes = [Address, addressMutation, addressQuery];
const mergedTypes = mergeTypeDefs(toMergeTypes);
export const addressResolverTypes = mergedTypes;
```